# Production Build in Next JS VS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, production

hope someone may guide me through the right way, im trying to run a React & Next Js Project on VS and I keep coming across the same problem which says :

```
Error: Could not find a production build in the 'C:\Users\isaac\OneDrive\Desktop\iteck_react\.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
    at NextNodeServer.getBuildId (C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\freact\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:169:23)
    at new Server (C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\freact\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:58:29)
    at new NextNodeServer (C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\freact\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:70:9)
    at NextServer.createServer (C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\freact\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:140:16)
    at async C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\freact\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:149:3``
```

package.json

```json
 "name": "iteck",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",    
    "export": "next build && next export",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "lightgallery": "^2.5.0",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "rc-slider": "^10.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.9",
    "sass": "^1.54.3",
    "swiper": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.3"
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require("path");

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "css")],
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
  devIndicators: {
    buildActivity: false,
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: false,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I tried installing the Node Modules again and running multiple requests but to no avail, could not manage to get it working, researched online but the solutions I found did not seem to work for me. I was expecting to be able to run the Next js project without problems on Vs, thinking I have set up well but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of what each `next foo` command does: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli.

Your package.json defines a few commands

```json
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
```

So for example, `npm run dev` will run `next dev` which is explained in the documentation I linked above.